# jQuery disable form element when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, jquery-events

I have a complicated jQuery form and I want to disable several form elements if a certain checkbox is checked. I'm using jQuery 1.3.2, and all the relevant plugins. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my HTML:

```
    <li id="form-item-15" class="form-item">
        <div class='element-container'>
            <select id="house_year_built" name="house_year_built" class="form-select" >
                 ...Bunch of options...
            </select>
            <input type="text" title="Original Purchase Price" id="house_purchase_price" name="house_purchase_price" class="form-text money" />
            <input type="text" title="Current Home Debt" id="house_current_debt" name="house_current_debt" class="form-text money" />
        </div>
        <span class="element-toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id="house_toggle" />
            <span>Do not own house</span>
        </span>
    </li>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.element-toggle input').change(function () { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).parents('div.element-container').children('input,select').attr('disabled', true);
    else $(this).parents('div.element-container').children('input,select').removeAttr('disabled'); });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that should be changed. First of all, the actual HTML structure doesn't match what you're querying for in JavaScript (specifically the `parents()` call). Secondly, binding to the `click` event will provide better support in IE since IE will sometimes wait to fire the `change` event until after the element loses focus.

```
$('.element-toggle input').bind('click', function () {
    var inputs = $(this).closest('li.form-item').find('div.element-container').children('input,select');

    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        inputs.attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        inputs.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Still not working, but looks like it should. Is it possible bind() is flakier than onchange, even if less compatible. I'll keep playing around. Hmm.

Comment: I ultimately eliminated the element-container class since it wasn't behaving for me and went with:
$('.element-toggle input').bind('click', function () {
    var inputs = $(this).closest('li.form-item').find('input,select');

    if   ($(this).attr('checked')) inputs.attr('disabled', true);
    else inputs.removeAttr('disabled');
    
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});

Thanks again, D

Answer (score 10):

just a tidbit: since jquery 1.6 you should not use `$(this).attr('checked')` which is always true, but rather `$(this).prop('checked')`.

it is also advisable to use `$(this).prop('disabled')` (to test whether the element is disabled), and `$(this).prop('disabled', newState)` rather than `attr`.

Comment: The if-statement can be also omitted and thus making a one-liner from that ```inputs.prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked'));```

Answer (score 1):

That was helpful. If anyone's looking for a plugin, here you go: http://s.technabled.com/jquery-foggle

Comment: Works but costs $3 or $15 and is not open source.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class='element-container'>` is not a parent for `$('.element-toggle input')` is your example