# If checkbox is checked then enable EditorFor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, attributes

I would like my Checkbox to disable EditorsFor if it is unchecked and enable them if it is checked. I know I have to use JavaScript, I found some codes in net, but it seems that they don't work.

Here is my View code:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_PartialError");}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

(...)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Czy_zuzywalny, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Czy_zuzywalny)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Czy_zuzywalny, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ilosc_minimalna, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ilosc_minimalna, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ilosc_minimalna, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ilosc_optymalna, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ilosc_optymalna, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ilosc_optymalna, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    (...)
}
```

And I wrote something like this and put in js file (ofc at the end of this code is ), but it doesn't work...

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#Czy_zuzywalny").click(function ()
    {
        if ($("#Ilosc_minimalna").attr("disabled") == "")
        {
            $("#Ilosc_minimalna").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#Ilosc_optymalna").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#Ilosc_minimalna").attr("value", "0");
            $("#Ilosc_optymalna").attr("value", "0");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#Ilosc_minimalna").attr("disabled", "");
            $("#Ilosc_optymalna").attr("disabled", "");
        }
    });
});
```

Nothing happens even if I check or uncheck my checkbox. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806830/jquery-checkbox-to-enable-disable-text-input-and-add-remove-default-value, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799255/jquery-disable-form-element-when-checkbox-is-checked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322630/jquery-checkbox-disable-enable-secondary-inputs-based-on-checkbox-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your jQuery code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Czy_zuzywalny").click(function () {

        if ($("#Ilosc_minimalna").is('[disabled=disabled]')) {
            $("#Ilosc_minimalna").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#Ilosc_optymalna").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#Ilosc_minimalna").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#Ilosc_optymalna").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#Ilosc_minimalna").attr("value", "0");
            $("#Ilosc_optymalna").attr("value", "0");                
        }            
    });
});
```

The if condition on your code never actually evaluates to true because in an enabled input, the 'disabled' attribute doesn't have a value of an empty string. it just doesn't exist (thus the use of `removeAttr("disabled")`).

**UPDATE:** Working [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/endizhupani/8euws0Lu/)

**UPDATE 2:**

In order to add the script in the Create view and have it show after the jQuery script tag in the rendered HTML do this:

First add a call to RenderSection in your Layout file **just before** the closing `</body>` tag like this:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

This will give you the ability to include a 'scripts' section in your views, the contents of which, will appear instead of the RenderSection call in the final HTML. Note that the `required: false` parameter specifies that you don't have to include this section in every view.

Then in your Create view, outside of any section add this:

```
@section scripts {
<script src="/scripts/CheckBoxItemCreate.js"></script>
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Cezar Have you included the necessary jQuery references? I updated the answer to include a JSFiddle with the working code. If you click the javascript settings button you will see that jQuery 3.1.1 is included

Comment: Well, I see it works on JSFiddle, but I don't have inputs. I have EditorFors, how should I change it to work the same as your code?

Comment: @Cezar EditorFor will ultimately generate an input in HTML. If you view the source of your page from the browser, you will see that each EditorFor has generated an <input> element. So, +- a few attributes (that do not make a difference) the HTML markup that is generated will be the same as the one on JSFiddle

Comment: Correct, they look like
`<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Pole Czy zużywalny jest wymagane." id="Czy_zuzywalny" name="Czy_zuzywalny" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Czy_zuzywalny" type="hidden" value="false" />`

`<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Ilość minimalna must be a number." data-val-required="Pole Ilość minimalna jest wymagane." id="Ilosc_minimalna" name="Ilosc_minimalna" type="text" value="" />`

but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Have a look at the page's source from the browser to see if all the jquery references are included

Comment: Yes, there is a script which I add in Create view
`<script src="/scripts/CheckBoxItemCreate.js"></script>`
And standard scripts from _Layout
`<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MVCDataTableJqueryBootStrap-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: @Cezar And the script appears after the tag that has the reference for jQuery?

Comment: Yes it appears but it **must** appear **after** the jquery tag to work. So `<script src="/scripts/CheckBoxItemCreate.js">` must appear **after** `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js">`, because if it appears before that tag, like in your case, it will not be able to execute jQuery code

Comment: OK now it works, I had to cut and paste script into _Layout, but I don't need this screept to load on every page, how can I paste it into Create view to appear after jquery? At the beginning I pasted it at the end of Create view file, but it loads before jquerry.

Comment: @Cezar updated the post to answer your question. Don't forget to upvote and mark as correct answer :)